# Sum of odd and even numbers in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Dataframe having three columns 'even', 'odd' and 'sum'. Even column have all the even numbers from 1 to 100 and odd column have all the odd numbers from 1 to 100. I want sum of both the columns of 'even' and 'odd' in the 'sum' column. Anyone help me out ?

Comment: Please share a sample input and expected output of your data frame.

Comment: No idea what your dataframe looks like, but this should be really simple: `df['sum'] = df[['even', 'odd']].sum(axis=1)`. But I recommend NOT calling your result column "sum".

Answer (score 1):

Try-

```
df['sum'] = df['even'] + df['odd']
```

Sample output-

```
    even   odd   sum
0     2     1     3
1     4     3     7
```